# Adding Image to the Excel in phpexcel in php

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am taking the example from [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

I just tried with passing value in GET Method, I am done with that.

Now i am trying to add image in the a3 coloumn.

**Reference Code :**

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['value'];
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', $value)
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

**Example Code for inserting image :**

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/officelogo.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

But i don't understanding how to insert the jpg in the a3 coloumn or any other coloumn in the excel file that i import.

**How can i do this ?**

Comment: please visit for full code :-  http://www.7logic.info/2017/04/convert-excel-plus-image-to-pdf-using.html

Comment: @Akshath dead link

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Specifying coordinates for the image might help, as per the examples and the documentation

```
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A3');
```

Note that an image isn't **in** a cell/column/row, but **overlaid** over the main sheet at the same position as that cell/column/row

Comment: Thanks sir, But while i include that in my laravel application like this **require_once base_path().'\public\assets\excel\Classes\PHPExcel.php';** It is showing error that `Cannot redeclare class PHPExcel`

Comment: It points me the line inside the PHPExcel.php **class PHPExcel
{** in the Black screen.

Comment: That error is not what your original question asked. If you're using Laravel, why not use something like https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel as a wrapper around PHPExcel

Comment: Yes, i agree.. SO i should have a fresh installation of laravel excel ?

Answer (score 10):

Read my article,

http://www.7codes.info/post/8/export-excel-files-with-images-using-php-excel-library

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();    //create object for Worksheet drawing
$objDrawing->setName('Customer Signature');        //set name to image
$objDrawing->setDescription('Customer Signature'); //set description to image
$signature = $reportdetails[$rowCount][$value];    //Path to signature .jpg file
$objDrawing->setPath($signature);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(25);                       //setOffsetX works properly
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(10);                       //setOffsetY works properly
$objDrawing->setCoordinates($column.$cell);        //set image to cell
$objDrawing->setWidth(32);                 //set width, height
$objDrawing->setHeight(32);  

$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());  //save
```

Answer (score 6):

I solve logo or images insert/showing problem use below code:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('test_img');
$objDrawing->setDescription('test_img');
$objDrawing->setPath('../images/logo.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');                      
//setOffsetX works properly
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(5); 
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(5);                
//set width, height
$objDrawing->setWidth(100); 
$objDrawing->setHeight(35); 
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```